# Search for Multiple Excel File Types in Directory

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7

I'm trying to create a script that will search for excel files within a single directory. The script will search for a substring in the file name, then record the name of the file which contains that substring to a new excel file.

I'm new to Python and my programming skills are still sub-par, so I'm looking for a starting point here.

Here's some code that I've found and tried to modify, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Here's the traceback:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\py_compile.py", line 106, in compile with open(file, 'U') as f:
>
> IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('U') or filename: ''

```
    import os, fnmatch

    start_dir = os.getenv('C:\Test')

    def excelfiles(pattern):
        file_list = []
        for root, files in os.walk(start_dir):
            for filename in files:
                if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename.lower(), pattern):
                    if filename.endswith(".xls") or filename.endswith(".xlsx") or filename.endswith(".xlsm"):
                        file_list.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
        return file_list

    file_list = excelfiles('*SP*')
    for i in file_list: 
        print i
```

***Edit***
So here's what I came up with after considering the recommendations. It still doesn't work and I'm not sure why (hence "supernoob").

```
    import os, fnmatch

    def excelfiles(pattern, start_dir = 'C:\Test'):
        file_list = []
        for root, subdir, files in os.walk(start_dir):
            for filename in files:
                if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename.lower(), pattern):
                    if filename.endswith(".xls", ".xlsx", ".xlsm"):
                        file_list.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
        return file_list

    file_list = excelfiles('*SP*')
    for i in file_list: 
        print i
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\py_compile.py", line 106, in compile
>       with open(file, 'U') as f:
>
> IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('U') or filename: ''

Comment: define "doesn't seem to work for me"

Comment: Sorry, it throws multiple errors.
"Missing module docstring"
"Redefining 'file_list' from outer scope"
"Invalid constant name 'file_list'" etc

Comment: So post the traceback.

Comment: No, edit your question so that it includes the traceback in a readable form.

Comment: I will tell you one thing: `os.getenv('C:\Test')` is not likely to be what you really want. `os.getenv` is for retrieving environment variables. Environment variables are the things that show up when you open a command prompt (the one that comes with Windows, not Python) and type `set` at the prompt.

Comment: Thanks John, any recommended commands for opening the directory?

Comment: check out the glob module

Comment: Hi, @supernoob did my edit (the double backslash) resolve your issue. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. 

PS: You're missing parentheses in your `filename.endswith` method please refer to the last line of my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current error is **IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('U') or filename**.

A single backslash is an escape character (used to encode special characters such as new lines `\n` or tabs `\t`). When you want python to print a backslash, we need to use a double backslash.
`C:\\Test` This should resolve this error.

**Other possible errors:**

1. How you have defined `start_dir`:

`start_dir` should not be defined using os.getenv. Currently, `os.getenv` looks up `C:\Test` in the os.environ dictionary which maps names such as environment variables such as `HOME` or `Users` to their values (in this example, the home directory or user name). You should check if this is returning what you expect, but I suspect it isn't. I would instead just define the directory for startdir as a string, `startdir = 'C:\Test`.

I would bring `start_dir` within the scope of the function. My suggestion would be to do `def excelfiles(pattern, startdir = 'C:\Test'):` This way you have the option of providing a different directory when calling the function but if you don't the function will use the default value which is `C:\Test`.

2. Unpacking the tuple returned by `os.walk()` in for loop:

In every pass of the loop, `os.walk` will return a tuple with three values:
the name of the directory it found, list of subdirectories in the current directory, and list of files in the current directory. To unpack a tuple of 3 values, you need 3 variables in your for loop. Your current for loop `for root, files in os.walk(start_dir):` only accommodates two values. You need to change this to `for root, subdir, files in os.walk(start_dir):`

**A suggestion:**

To simplify your code I'd suggest looking at the documentation for str.endswith. str.endswith can accept a tuple and will return true if str has one of the suffices in the tuple. In your case, `filename.endswith(".xls") or filename.endswith(".xlsx") or filename.endswith(".xlsm"):` can be simplified to  `filename.endswith((".xls", ".xlsm", ".xlsx"))`

Edit: I provided the backslash solution for the IOError.